# Get AuthToken for SharepointOnline in dotnet core

Tags: sharepoint, .net-core, oauth-2.0

I'm able to get an auth token for Sharepoint in Postman using the following parameters:

URL : https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/{tenantId}/tokens/OAuth/2

Method: POST

Headers :
 - Content-type: application/json

Body :

- Resource: 00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/{myorganization}.sharepoint.com@{tenantId}
- grant_type: client_credentials
- client_id: {appId}@{tenantId}
- client_secret: {myclientsecret}

Now, I'm trying to reproduce this POST http call in dotnet core, but I'm getting always a 400 (Bad request) response..

Here is my code :

```
var body = new AuthBodySPO
            {
                Resource = resource,
                client_id = appId,
                client_secret = appSecret,
                grant_type = "client_credentials"
            };

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
                using (var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                {
                    request.Content = stringContent;

                    using (var response = await client
                        .SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)
                        .ConfigureAwait(false))
                    {
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to perform the POST operation through POST man tool? Instead of javascript coding.... I am also facing same issue... everything seems fine but getting invalid credentials 400 error in POST man tool... registered the client ID and client secret successfully but not working.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me, after registered your app, did you give the authorization ? Like in this link : https://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/

Comment: Authorization means in appenv page inside the big text box Xml you mean right?

Comment: If you follow some URL, would you please share that...

Comment: I referred an URL everything was fine but while testing that through POST man to check the POST operation... it says invalid credential.

Comment: Yes I mean the text box Xml, maybe you have forgot the tenantId after the @, for the clientId ?

Comment: It worked for me following the URL, I mentioned on my first reply

Comment: What a co-incident !!! I was also following the same URL. I think I have found my mistake Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web"     -in this scope url I was passing my actual site URL - I think this should be as is. Am I right?